# Font File Won't Delete

Tags: java, file, delete-file

I'm trying to install PhpStorm and after a long story it looks like I have some bad fonts getting in the way of Java.

I'm completely new to Java but I found this code to loop through my fonts and find the bad ones.  I've modified it to delete the bad font, but it won't delete.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

public class myFontCheck {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Font[] fonts = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts();
    for (int i = 0; i < fonts.length; i++) {
      final Font font = fonts[i];
      final String name = font.getFontName();

      if (font.canDisplay('a') &&
        font.canDisplay('z') &&
        font.canDisplay('A') &&
        font.canDisplay('Z') &&
        font.canDisplay('0') &&
        font.canDisplay('1')) {
        //System.out.println(" OK.");
      } else {
        File file = new File("c:\\Windows\\Fonts\\" + name + ".ttf");
        if(file.exists()) {
          System.out.println("Bad Font: " + name);
          file.delete();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm assuming it's a file permission conflict but I can't figure out how to change the permissions. Do I need to run this as an administrator?

Or.. can you show me how to open just the bad files into an explorer window so that I can 'Select All'?

Comment: You should run the app as administrator in order to work. By the way, why would you want to delete a font? Also, maybe the path could be wrong depending on your OS

Comment: Hi Luiggi, according to JetBrains' customer support, my computer has some fonts that are preventing PhpStorm from loading.  What do I type in the command line to run it as an administrator?

Comment: If you are running this from an IDE (NetBeans, Eclipse, etc) run the IDE as administrator by right-clicking the exe and using *Run as Administrator* option. If you run this from console (cmd), then open the console as administrator and execute the program

Comment: Thank you guys for helping out.  I've edited the code to check if the file exists, and it does print out the file name, but does not delete the file.  I ran it as administrator as well but still not deleting.. any other thoughts?  Is it pretty tough to have all the bad fonts listed in an explorer window?

Comment: Instead of deleting the file, get the list of the files and delete them manually. I ran the code in my pc to list the *bad* fonts and they were just 3.

Comment: Definitely, that's what I've been doing all day, unfortunately I downloaded and installed one of those '5,000' font zip files so I have about 300, which wouldn't be bad at all except that there's the 15 second lag between each delete.  But for sure, if I can't figure out another way, I'll manually delete them.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (font.canDisplay('a') &&
    font.canDisplay('z') &&
    font.canDisplay('A') &&
    font.canDisplay('Z') &&
    font.canDisplay('0') &&
    font.canDisplay('1')) {
    //System.out.println(" OK.");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Bad Font: " + name);
    File file = new File("c:\\Windows\\Fonts\\" + name + ".ttf");
    file.delete();
  }
```

Uncomment the "bad fonts line".  Does anything get printed out when you run the app?  I suspect no, because although you might not like the way the font displays, canDisplay might return true.

Alternatively, the "new File", string construction might result in something incorrect.  I would try printing that out as well, and checking the file system for that file.

Sort of like this:

```
  } else {
    System.out.println("Bad Font: " + name);
    String fn = "c:\\Windows\\Fonts\\" + name + ".ttf";
    System.out.println("Trying to delete: " + fn);
    File file = new File(fn);
    file.delete();
  }
```

Comment: Hi Pete, I gave it a try but it didn't delete.  It did print both 'Bad Font' and 'Trying to delete' with the correct file names and path.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: First, I would cut, and then in a dos window do a:
dir <paste>.  Does the file list?  If not then you don't have the file name correctly.

If it does, can you delete the file manually?

If you can delete it manually, then you need run the java app in the admin mode.  If not then the permissions on the file may be locked.  It is about taking steps, that lead you to the solution to a problem.

Comment: Sometimes it is enough to rename the problem file, so the new file is no longer trying to overwrite it.  Are you sure that no other application has this particular font open?  That would also cause a problem with overwriting it.